# Unable to login to my rails app after implenting secure_headers gem in my local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-security-policy

My website uses Rails 3, in which I am trying to fix CSP(Content Security Policy) related issues. 
I have installed **[secure_headers gem](https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders)**.

Then after adding the below code in Application Controller:

```
 SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
    config.secure_cookies = true # mark all cookies as "secure"
    config.hsts = "max-age=#{20.years.to_i}; includeSubdomains; preload"
    config.x_frame_options = "DENY"
    config.x_content_type_options = "nosniff"
    config.x_xss_protection = "1; mode=block"
    config.x_download_options = "noopen"
    config.x_permitted_cross_domain_policies = "none"
    config.csp = {
      # "meta" values. these will shaped the header, but the values are not included in the header.
      report_only:  true,     # default: false
      preserve_schemes: true, # default: false. Schemes are removed from host sources to save bytes and discourage mixed content.

      # directive values: these values will directly translate into source directives
      default_src: %w(https: 'self'),
      # frame_src: %w('self' *.twimg.com itunes.apple.com),
      # connect_src: %w(wws:),
      font_src: %w('self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff ),
      img_src: %w('self' https://*.youtube.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome data: ),
      media_src: %w('self' https://img.youtube.com ),
      object_src: %w('self'),
      script_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js),
      style_src: %w('self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css https://fonts.googleapis.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css http://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700 http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700),
      base_uri: %w('self'),
      child_src: %w('self'),
      # form_action: %w('self' ),
      frame_ancestors: %w('none'),
      plugin_types: %w(application/x-shockwave-flash),
      # block_all_mixed_content: true, # see [http://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/](http://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/)
      # upgrade_insecure_requests: true, # see https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/
      report_uri: %w(https://report-uri.io/example-csp)
    }

  end
```

I am unable to perform login action. Is there any other way to implement CSP in rails, I am implementing it in a wrong way. I could not find any blog which explains implementation of the gem. Please help.

**Update:**
On changing the value of **secure_cookies** to **false** I am able to login to my website, but then I am sure making secure_cookies false will have some bad effect on my app.

Comment: It sounds like the login isn't happening over https, the cookies are getting marked as secure, and then are not included on subsequent requests. I opened https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders/issues/243 to handle this. Using https would also fix this.

Comment: Thanks @oreoshake, I guess then while testing on my local I would have to keep it `secure_cookies: false`. The only problem is if someone tries to access the website on `http`, they will not be able to login. One more doubt, if I make **upgrade_insecure_requests** to `true` will it help?

Comment: @oreoshake, can you tell me any other way/approach to fix CSP related issues, in rails 4 I found that most of security features are provided by default but I do not want to upgrade to Rails 4 as the website is huge and will take months.

Comment: @oreoshake just one last doubt, which one's better to implement `secure_headers` gem or meta` tag (something like this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ;">`). Do both of them give the same result? (because I was using [this](https://securityheaders.io) online website for checking the implementation).

Comment: Some options aren't available in the meta tag (report-uri, frame-ancestors I think, maybe more?). The meta tag is typically used for static content but really the choice is up to you.

Comment: Upgrade insecure requests will only affect resources loaded. Using https with strict transport security will force users to use https for all pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @oreoshake, you can post the first comment as answer, would be happy to accept it as a solution. I will be implementing secure_headers in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the login isn't happening over https, the cookies are getting marked as secure, and then are not included on subsequent requests. I opened github.com/twitter/secureheaders/issues/243 to handle this. Using https and strict transport security would also fix this.